# Delete mysql records is not working in codeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my controller function:

```
function delete_article($title){

    if ($this->session->userdata('User') && $this->session->userdata('User') == 'admin@example.com') {

        $this->load->model('Article', 'Article', TRUE);
        $this->Article->delete_article_db($title);

        redirect('admin/user_article');
    } else {
        redirect('');
    }
}
```

And this is my model function for deleting the database record:

```
 function delete_article_db($title) {
    $this->db->where('Title', $title);
    $this->db->delete('article');
}
```

When I run this code, nothing gets deleted. However, the code does not fire any errors or warnings.

This is my MySQL table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
   `Name` text NOT NULL,
   `Email` text NOT NULL,
   `Phone` text NOT NULL,
   `Address` text NOT NULL,
   `Literature` text NOT NULL,
   `Title` text NOT NULL,
   `Submission_Name` text NOT NULL,
   `Additional_Name` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Check CodeIgnitor logs?

Comment: did you check that there's an article with this title? Did you check server logs?

Comment: Does it work with `$this->db->delete('article', array('Title' => $title));` ?

Comment: Database class is preloaded?

Comment: @André Sir not working with your solution.. :(

Comment: @Muhammad As user2486495 said before, check CodeIgniter's logs for any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of a wild guess, but looking at your controller method, and the variable names, I'm assuming you're passing the *title* via url, something like

```
http://example.com/admin/delete/Title to be deleted
```

Which leads me to think your query is not working because of encoding of the spaces in the url (or other characters) which won't match the not encoded spaces in your db.

Try with:

```
function delete_article_db($title) {
    $this->db->where('Title', rawurldecode($title) );
    $this->db->delete('article');
}
```

Comment: PERFECT WORKS.. FOR ME NOW.. THANK YOU VERY MUCH SIR.. I AM SOLVING THIS FROM LAST 2 HOURS THANK YOU AGAIN SIR.. :)

Comment: Glad it worked! :) As an advice: always `var_dump()` a variable when you're not sure about its content (like in _where_ clause)