# I cant delete from mysql with codeigneter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I can't delete from `MySQL` with codeigniter.

My controller:

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $this->load->model('dele');
    $this->dele->delettest($id);                   
}
```

and my model:

```
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('table');
```

but the record does not get deleted.

Comment: Your delete functions seem right, are you sure you are passing the right ID into the controller?

Comment: I test wiht this url

http://localhost/gestionfacile/index.php/Editer/delete/174

but not deleted from db Im sure the id exist and the right name of db and colomns

Comment: try $this->db->last_query(); this prints your last query

Comment: nothing display my problem exectly smae the 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224362/delete-mysql-records-is-not-working-in-codeigniter

I applied the solution but not work for me I add tha  rawurldecode befer id not work

Comment: Have you var dumped your $id and made sure your getting it?

Answer (score 1):

Without the models. try to do this in your controller:

```
public function delete($id) { 
$this->db->delete('your_table', array('id' => $id)); //pass here the array with $id
}
/*
It will produce:
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE id=1;
*/
```

Comment: I am very very very sorry really I am too sorry 
I work all the day I try wiht the wrong Id 

form the frist is work just I was try wiht the wrong id 
really Iam very sorry